# Any experiences with Web2Cal?

Tags: web, calendar

I need a calendar-widget for my website. This calendar needs to be very flexible. An option is to write it from scratch, but I think, if kept at a reasonable price, it would be a better option to buy the code.

So far I've come up with [Web2Cal](http://www.web2cal.com/) which looks great. I downloaded the free-version, to see how it would be to work with, but I feel like I'm running short on documentation. Does anyone have any experiences with this 'widget'? Is it worth spending some dollars on it?

Double bonus question:

- Do you know of any better place to find documentation on Web2Cal than their primary website?
- Do you know of similar tools, which you liked (commercial or free-to-use)?

Thanks in advance :)

[EDIT] If it makes any difference, the server code is being done i ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try daypilot.org? that has a component for .NET

Web2Cal is certainly nice, I noticed that their support system is nice. They respond to all questions. Web2Cal is more flexible.

If you feel daypilot satisfies your needs go for it. 
For some reason, I feel web2cal is more easy to customize and versatile than daypilot. To make up for the documentation, their support is pretty good. I guess that is true for all new softwares. So take advantage of that feature, post like 300 questions to them to get your work done.. ! saves you a whole lot of headache.